# FIND_IN_SET in mysql

Tags: mysql

```
select `ID_DOCUMENT` from document WHERE 
find_in_set((SELECT t.id_tag from tags t WHERE t.tag_name="example" LIMIT 1),`TAGS_DOCUMENT`)
```

`tags_document` is equal to (1,2,3,4)

The problem is that this query is throwing me result 0.

Comment: Does `TAGS_DOCUMENT` have the parenthesis (`()`) around it?  Because for this to work, it shouldn't.

Comment: not mate if I remove the parenthesis gets Error

Comment: Do you get an actual error?  Or do you just get 0 rows?  Are you sure a row exists that fits this criteria?

Comment: Your SQL query works for me: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b02b7/1

Comment: if  i remove the brackets show me error #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax;  and with brackets show me 0

Comment: What *exactly* do your `document` and `tags` tables look like?  What format is the data in?  What parenthesis are you removing?  I meant does the `tags_document` field *literally* have parenthesis in it or not?  Your query is fine as written.

Comment: in the table document field TAGS_DOCUMENT is 1,2,3,4,5 and the table TAGS the fields are id_tag and tag_name id_tag = 1 tag_name = 'example'

Comment: gracias amigo me ayudaste mucho Dios te bendiga !!

Answer (score 1):

```
 SELECT `id_document` 
   FROM document d
   JOIN tags t
     ON FIND_IN_SET(t.id_tag,d.tags_document)
  WHERE t.tag_name = "example" ;
```

but please consider normalizing your data